# Network Error axios in react

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

Когда я делаю запрос через postman на сервер, при ошибке мне всегда возвращается message, но если делать запрос через клиент, то ошибка не приходит.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой ответ приходит через postman:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А через клиент приходит вот такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компонента, которая делает запрос:

```
import { Alert, Button, Dialog, DialogActions, DialogTitle, Grid, DialogContent, Snackbar, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray, useFormik } from 'formik';
import agent from "../../../../../../agent/agent";
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { useState } from 'react';
import "yup-phone";

const styles = {
    modal: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '50%',
        left: '50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
        width: 400,
        bgcolor: 'background.paper',
        borderRadius: 2,
        boxShadow: 24,
        p: 4,
    },
    submit: {
        margin: '15px 15px 0 15px'
    }
}

const ValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    type: Yup.string()
        .required('Обязательное поле')
        .matches(/^(ip|jp)$/g, 'Невалидный тип'),
    name: Yup.string()
        .required('Обязательное поле'),
    inn: Yup.string()
        .required('Обязательное поле')
        .min(9, 'Минимальная длина 9 символов')
        .max(12, 'Максимальная длина 12 символов'),
    kpp: Yup.string()
        .required('Обязательное поле')
        .min(9, 'Минимальная длина 9 символов')
        .max(9, 'Максимальная длина 9 символов'),
    ogrn: Yup.string()
        .required('Обязательное поле')
        .min(13, 'Минимальная длина 13 символов')
        .max(15, 'Максимальная длина 15 символов'),
    email: Yup.string()
        .required('Обязательное поле')
        .email('Невалидный адрес почты'),
    phone: Yup.string()
        .required('Обязательное поле')
        .matches(/^(\+?\d{0,4})?\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{4}\)?)?$/, 'Невалидный номер'),
    address: Yup.string()
        .required('Обязательное поле'),
    ceoName: Yup.string()
        .required('Обязательное поле')
});

const AddOrganizationModal = ({ isOpen, handleClose }) => {

    const [isOpenAlert, setIsOpenAlert] = useState(false);
    const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState('');

    const closeAlert = () => {
        setIsOpenAlert(false)
        setAlertMessage('')
    }

    const openAlert = (err) => {
        setIsOpenAlert(true)
        setAlertMessage(typeof err === 'string' ? err : 'Произошла ошибка при отправке формы')
    }

    const handleCloseModal = (withNewOrganizations = false) => {
        handleClose(withNewOrganizations)
        formik.handleReset()
    }

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            type: "",
            name: "",
            inn: "",
            kpp: "",
            ogrn: "",
            email: "",
            phone: "",
            address: "",
            ceoName: ""
        },
        validationSchema: ValidationSchema,
        onSubmit: async (values) => {
            await agent.post(`/organizations`, values).then((res) => {
                handleCloseModal(true)
            }).catch((err) => {
                openAlert(err.response?.message|| err.message || err)
            })
        }
    });

    const onSubmit = () => {
        formik.handleSubmit()
    }

    return <>
        <Dialog
            open={isOpen}
            onClose={() => handleCloseModal()}
            fullWidth
            maxWidth="md"
        >
            <DialogTitle>
                <Typography variant="h3">
                    Создание организации
                </Typography>
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <Box pt={1}>
                    <form style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignContent: 'center' }}>
                        <Box mb={2}>
                            <TextField
                                style={styles.field}
                                fullWidth
                                name="type"
                                label="Тип"
                                value={formik.values.type}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                error={formik.touched.type && Boolean(formik.errors.type)}
                                helperText={formik.touched.type && formik.errors.type}
                            />
                        </Box>
                        <Box mb={2}>
                            <TextField
                                style={styles.field}
                                fullWidth
                                name="name"
                                label="Название"
                                value={formik.values.name}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                error={formik.touched.name && Boolean(formik.errors.name)}
                                helperText={formik.touched.name && formik.errors.name}
                            />
                        </Box>
                        <Box mb={2}>
                            <TextField
                                style={styles.field}
                                fullWidth
                                name="inn"
                                label="ИНН"
                                value={formik.values.inn}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                error={formik.touched.inn && Boolean(formik.errors.inn)}
                                helperText={formik.touched.inn && formik.errors.inn}
                            />
                        </Box>
                        <Box mb={2}>
                            <TextField
                                style={styles.field}
                                fullWidth
                                name="kpp"
                                label="КПП"
                                value={formik.values.kpp}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                error={formik.touched.kpp && Boolean(formik.errors.kpp)}
                                helperText={formik.touched.kpp && formik.errors.kpp}
                            />
                        </Box>
                        <Box mb={2}>
                            <TextField
                                style={styles.field}
                                fullWidth
                                name="ogrn"
                                label="ОГРН"
                                value={formik.values.ogrn}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                error={formik.touched.ogrn && Boolean(formik.errors.ogrn)}
                                helperText={formik.touched.ogrn && formik.errors.ogrn}
                            />
                        </Box>
                        <Box mb={2}>
                            <TextField
                                style={styles.field}
                                fullWidth
                                name="email"
                                label="Почта"
                                value={formik.values.email}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
                                helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
                            />
                        </Box>
                        <Box mb={2}>
                            <TextField
                                style={styles.field}
                                fullWidth
                                name="phone"
                                label="Номер"
                                value={formik.values.phone}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                error={formik.touched.phone && Boolean(formik.errors.phone)}
                                helperText={formik.touched.phone && formik.errors.phone}
                            />
                        </Box>
                        <Box mb={2}>
                            <TextField
                                style={styles.field}
                                fullWidth
                                name="address"
                                label="Адрес"
                                value={formik.values.address}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                error={formik.touched.address && Boolean(formik.errors.address)}
                                helperText={formik.touched.address && formik.errors.address}
                            />
                        </Box>
                        <Box mb={2}>
                            <TextField
                                style={styles.field}
                                fullWidth
                                name="ceoName"
                                label="Имя ген. директора"
                                value={formik.values.ceoName}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                error={formik.touched.ceoName && Boolean(formik.errors.ceoName)}
                                helperText={formik.touched.ceoName && formik.errors.ceoName}
                            />
                        </Box>
                    </form>
                </Box>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Box px={2}>
                    <Grid container justifyContent="flex-end" spacing={1}>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => handleCloseModal()}
                                sx={{ textTransform: "initial", borderRadius: "4px", padding: "4px 24px" }}>
                                Отменить
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Button variant="contained" onClick={onSubmit}
                                sx={{ textTransform: "initial", borderRadius: "4px", padding: "4px 24px" }}>
                                Создать
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Box>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
        <Snackbar open={isOpenAlert} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={closeAlert}>
            <Alert onClose={closeAlert} severity="error" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
                {alertMessage}
            </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
    </>
};

export default AddOrganizationModal;
```

Тут создание agent axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://backend.pilorami.online",
    headers: {
        'x-auth-token': localStorage.getItem('jwt')
    }
})

export default axiosInstance
```

Comment: Cors настроен??

Comment: Не знаю, честно говоря, я на фронте работаю, к бэку доступа нет. Но просто если в postman приходит ошибка, а у меня нет, то, видимо на фронте что-то не то. Обновил вопрос, добавил информацию о том, как с фронта делаю запрос, может в нём что-то не то?

Comment: Добавьте код текстом, а не мкриншотами

Comment: Добавил код с компонентом и axios

Comment: Ну видимо надо настроить CORS.